# Should HTTP Based Micro Services always be Rest

Tags: rest, microservices

I'm currently developing a micro service that basically provides calculation services to other micro services. It does not store data or have any resources like a sales order. It only calls other micro services and then calculates metrics and prices to return a result.

I'm kind of struggling  trying to make a rest API with resources names that are nouns when all I do is calculate stuff and return results (more like an action).

So can we have a micro services that behaves more like an HTTP API than a Restful service (is it a bad practice, an anti pattern , an architecture smell, ....)

Regards

Comment: You don't have to use REST, RPC *can* be OK.

Comment: SOAP can be ok too, though it does not scale as well as REST because it stores sessions on the server, but stateless SOAP can work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use whatever you want and in your particular case I am pretty sure you won't see any drawbacks. From my point of view only difference with rest is mostly semantic -some people may also argue about cacheability but I don't think so-

Apart from rest/rpc creating microservices without any actual domain could cause a maintenance issue in the long run as you totally depend on some other microservices data whenever a change required in their side you may also need change this microservice. That is why I don't recommend those kind of calculation services unless you have a valid scalability requirement.